# Transparent border on input

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for help because I don't know how to do this transparent border on my input. What I want as result:

[image: Input]

I tried everything I've learned with `border` and `box-shadow` but I still don't know where am I messing. Could you help me? Even if I need to see an article to understand the way to do it.

```css
.location{
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.location .fas{
    padding:15px 15px 10px 15px;
    background-color: red;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    height:20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.location input[type=text]{
    padding:16px 11px 12px 11px;
    border:  1px solid rgba(0, 0,0,0.1);
    outline:none;
}

::placeholder{
    color:black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.location a:visited{
    color:white;
}

.location a {
    background-color: #0065FC;
    padding:14px 15px 10px 15px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:21px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="location">
  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Marseille, France" /><a
    href="#"
    >Rechercher</a
  >
</div>
```

Comment: That is not a border, it's a `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code below I have almost what you have in your screenshot. Take a look at it:

```css
.location{
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display : flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.location .fas{
    padding:15px 15px 10px 15px;
    background-color: red;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    height:20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.location input[type=text]{
    padding:16px 11px 12px 11px;
    border:  1px solid #F2F2F2;
  margin:0;
    outline:none;
}

::placeholder{
    color:black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.location a:visited{
    color:white;
}

.location a {
    background-color: #0065FC;
    padding:14px 15px 10px 15px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:21px;
    color : white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="location">
  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Marseille, France" /><a
    href="#"
    >Rechercher</a
  >
</div>
```